# Pick .class file from a folder

Tags: java

I have an interface Operator that has one method like so :

```
public interface Operator
{
    double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber);
}
```

Then I have four class (Plus,Minus,Divide,Multiply) that implement Operator like so:

```
public class Plus implements Operator
{   
    public double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}
public class Minus implements Operator
{
    public double calculate(double firstNumber,double secondNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }
}
```

And so on...
For handling operator I use Map :

```
    private static Map<String,Operator> operatorMap = new HashMap<String,Operator>();
    static
    {
        operatorMap.put("+", new Plus());
        operatorMap.put("-", new Minus());
        operatorMap.put("*", new Multiply());
        operatorMap.put("/", new Divide());
    }
double output = 0;
output = operatorMap.get(elementInExpression[2]).calculate(firstNumber,secondNumber);
```

Now I want to change My app to work dynamically that if I implement other class like % my app still work.For this I put .class file in a folder .I want to pick automatically from thic .class file  . In my opinion I should use Reflection API. Can anyone help me to use this API?(don't use Reflections because it is not part of java Reflection API)

Comment: [Creating Extensible Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to add `public static String operator = "*";` variable to your operator classes.

### Do it in a specific directory

```
File f = "\\classesfolder\\";

ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { f.toURI().toURL() }, getClass().getClassLoader(););

FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".class");
    }
  };
for (File classFile : f.listFiles(filter)) {
    try {
        // Remove the file extension
        String filename = classFile.getName().substring(0, filename.length() - 6);
        Class<? implements Operator> cls = loader.loadClass(filename);
        Operator operatorClass = (Operator) cls.newInstance();
        operatorMap.put(operatorClass.operator, operatorClass);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry what does this part of code do? Class<? implements Operator> cls = loader.loadClass(filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 6));

Comment: it removes files .class extension and loads class that implements Operator

Comment: @ Kael53 Sorry Iam new with java I cant understand your app For Example tis part :for (File classFile : f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".class");
    }
}))

Comment: it filters files by extension gets the ones with .class only.No problem bro everyone was new once 

Comment: becouse your statment are inner it becomes so compilicated to me i can't seprate the statment

Comment: its a class for filtering files

Comment: first you filter with .class then remove .class . I think filter with remove .class is work fine isn't it? becouse all files in folder are type of .class

Comment: Need to remove .class to load it

Comment: I am so sorry please help me  .Can you seprate this statment becouse it's so compilicated for (File classFile : f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".class");
    }
})) make it simple,seprate for statment

Comment: Edited is it clear now ? Check for this article http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-a-filenamefilter-to-display-a-subset-of-files-in-a-directory.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87969/discussion-between-kael53-and-marzie).